# How to correct shifted x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]The x-axis is shifted to the right and I cant figure out why nor how to fix it?

```
plt.hist(df['# Payments Made'][my_vals],bins = 'auto')
```

The 0 on the x-axis should line up with the 0 on the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Try limiting your x-axis to 0 and above:

```
plt.xlim(left=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
plt.xlim(0,)
```